# Foreach role_id HTML select options

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, selected

I'm updating a small page where I can update a users info.

I have this query, where I join two database tabels:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN roles ON roles.id = users.`role_id` WHERE users.id=$id
```

To output the the name of the role according to the role id, i've created the variable $role

```
$role = $result["role_name"];
```

So that I can outbut it just by echoing `$role`

What I would like to be able to do, is to have a  form where I can select the users role. And also display the users current role with the selected attribute.

Something similar to this (my old solution):

```
<select name="role">                    
<?php
if ($role == 'Admin')
{
echo "<option value='Admin' Selected>";
}
else
{
echo "<option value='Admin'>";
}
echo "Admin </option>";

if ($role == 'User')
{
echo "<option value='User' Selected>";
}
else 
{
echo "<option value='User'>";
}
echo "User </option>";

?>
</select>
```

But as you can see, this was not very scalable. If i added a new role to my DB I would have to manually update my select code with another if statement.

Therefor I was thinking that it could be a possibility to use a foreach statement instead. But I simply can't wrap my head around how to mark the users current role with the Selected attribute.

To get all my roles in an array, I've done this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM roles");
$sql->execute ();
$roles = $sql->fetchAll ();
```

And the array will look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [role_name] => Admin ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [role_name] => User ) )
```

Comment: Just put the if statement inside your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could populate an array of roles from your database in this format:

```
$roles = array( "Admin" => 1, "User" => 2, ...);
```

then create the options like this between your select tags:

```
foreach($roles as $k => $v)
{
    $s = $role_id == $v ? "selected" : "";
    echo("<option value='$v' $s>$k</option>");
}
```